# LAMP Mysql PDO FETCH_ASSOC is not working

Tags: mysql, php, lamp

I have a PHP script and it works well on hosting or on WAMP (in Windows), but when I try to run it on LAMP (in Ubuntu), it gives me this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on string in /var/www/html/link/app/core/class.system.php:263 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/link/app/pages/user/home.php(6): system->site() #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/link/app/core/class.system.php on line 263
```

Here is my code:

```php
public function site(){
    $site = $this->connect()->query("SELECT * FROM system")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $site;
}
```

This *only* happens on my Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Not about Ubuntu, you might as well post on [so]

Comment: It's only happens on my ubuntu machine so I thought that this was the right place to ask.

Comment: That information is crucial, [edit] your post and add it.

Comment: @Liso That's the difference between [WAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)#WAMP) and [LAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)): the "W" stands for Windows and the "L" stands for Linux.

Comment: Something in your `$this->connect()` is returning a string instead of an object.  Better check that method.  Your question title is misleading -- it isn't `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` that is the problem. Are you requiring a file and the filepath directory separators are leaning the wrong way?